# CORS Issue with the /quote 0x API endpoint

Tags: dapps, 0x, cors

[image]I'm a new web2 fullstack web dev trying to get his feet in web3 and i've tried to create my first web3 dApp.

For the profile section and displaying a users' NFT and tokens balances I easily managed my way around the create-web3-dApp docs but i've been struggling for literal hours trying to find a fix to a problem I am having when calling the /quote endpoint of the 0x API; which keeps on returning a "cors" error?

I've tried different debugging methods  but nothing seems to work so I was wondering if anyone could have any hint on what the problem could be ?

PS: As you can see int he screenshot I don't have any issues with the /price endpoint which returns the correct object whereas /quote gets an error everytime

Thanks to anyone keen enough to help a beginner dev :)

Comment: I am not able to see the screenshot, can you post it?

Comment: @JoaoCampos Sorry for this mistake on my behalf, i've just updated the post to include the screenshot, let me know if you would need to look at my code :)

Comment: Did you manage to find the answer? I m also getting the same error